# Why is the following code not working? - null pointer exception in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, focus, setter

I am getting a null pointer exception on targetname in the setter, where I am setting the focusmanager.focuselement property. I am not sure why it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <Style x:Key="DesignerItemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll"/> 
                        <Control x:Name="ResizeDecorator" Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textboxName" Text="node" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="count" Text="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ResizeDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsManipulationEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="textboxName" Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="textboxName" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="textboxName"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see targetname in your code.  Start removing pieces of the style until it compiles to narrow down the issue.

Comment: what line are you refering to about the no targetname, i know where the problem is, it is the second setter in the triger for `IsManuplationEnabled`, the exception is saying that targetname is not instantiated, but the first setter in the same trigger is workgin fine

Comment: I don't think your focus manager is setup yet when the view is created.

Comment: do you have any suggestions about how I go around that.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  Maybe you can move the focus setting to a data template out side the main style?  That way the attempt to access the focus manager won't be until after it's instantiated....